# need help writing test for a global controller

Tags: unit-test

I'm trying to adapt a type ahead controller whose code i found on the web. It looks like this:

```
global class autoCompleteController{
    @RemoteAction
    global static SObject[] findSObjects(string obj, string qry, string addFields) {
        .......
        return L;
   }
}
```

Of course, i can't use it without a test. My test looks like this:

```
@isTest
public class autoCompleteControllerTest{
   @isTest private static void testSiteName(){
    HRTC_Site__c s = new HRTC_Site__c(Site_Name__c='testme');
    insert s;
    List<sObject> L = autoCompleteController.findSObjects('HRTC_Site__c','testme','Site_Name__c');
    system.assertequals(L.size(), 1);
}
}
```

When i run the test it reports success.... but it give me 0 lines of coverage. Can anyone give me a clue about why it's not being counted as covering the one method in the class ?

Comment: This link should help you out. http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/apex/message-id/81664/print-single-message/false/page/1

Comment: Are you definitely running the right test? Looks legit so it could be that you're running tests from a different class. Also, where are you running the tests? I know I've seen bad result data in the IDE before now.

Comment: There has historically been a bug that would cause Salesforce to report incorrect code coverage results. Try clearing out the previous test result histories first.

Answer (score 5):

that's from my blog post I think! I don't always include test classes on the blog because  I don't want people blindly copying and pasting. Looks like you've done some thinking around it, and your test class looks like it should work. Here's my test class. It checks for various potential problems:

```
@isTest
private class AutoCompleteTest{
    static testMethod void acTest(){
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;
        // Test with a basic search 
        sObject[] s1 = autoCompleteController.findSObjects('Account', 'test', '');
        System.assert(s1.size() > 0);

        // Test with an additional field
        sObject[] s2 = autoCompleteController.findSObjects('Account', 'test', 'TickerSymbol');
        System.assert(s2.size() > 0);

        // Test with an invalid object name
        try {
            sObject[] s3 = autoCompleteController.findSObjects('InvalidObject', 'test', '');
        }
        catch (Exception e) {   
          System.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), 'Object name InvalidObject not valid');
        }

        // Test with a valid object and invalid field
        try {
            sObject[] s4 = autoCompleteController.findSObjects('Account', 'test', 'InvalidField');
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
          System.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), 'Additional Field InvalidField not valid for object Account');  
        }
    }
}
```